Keycloak exception: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest.authority()" is null
I installed Keycloak locally, I did everything according to the guide: I created a realm “test-realm”, in it there was a client “test-client” and a user “user1” with the password 123456.
When I contact the endpoint to get a token (http://localhost:8180/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token) I get an error:
2024-04-10 16:20:26,836 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest.authority()" is null
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext.getRequestHost(VertxResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:194)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ResteasyReactiveRequestContext.getAuthority(ResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:481)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.jaxrs.UriInfoImpl.getBaseUri(UriInfoImpl.java:131)
    at org.keycloak.urls.HostnameProvider.getScheme(HostnameProvider.java:51)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider.fromFrontEndUrl(DefaultHostnameProvider.java:181)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider.getScheme(DefaultHostnameProvider.java:90)
    at org.keycloak.models.KeycloakUriInfo.<init>(KeycloakUriInfo.java:51)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakContext.getUri(DefaultKeycloakContext.java:78)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakContext.getUri(DefaultKeycloakContext.java:85)
    at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.checkSsl(TokenEndpoint.java:156)
    at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint$quarkusrestinvoker$processGrantRequest_6408e15340992839b66447750c221d9aaa837bd7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Post request with body
Keycloak server response
{
    "error": "unknown_error",
    "error_description": "For more on this error consult the server log at the debug level."
}

When Keycloak starts, the server writes the following logs:
2024-04-10 16:19:46,573 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: <request>, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false
2024-04-10 16:19:46,818 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2024-04-10 16:19:46,915 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2024-04-10 16:19:49,314 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (JPA Startup Thread) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2024-04-10 16:19:51,153 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2024-04-10 16:19:51,180 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_692571, Site name: null
2024-04-10 16:19:52,155 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Keycloak 24.0.2 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.8.3) started in 7.393s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8180
2024-04-10 16:19:52,155 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated.
2024-04-10 16:19:52,155 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-h2, keycloak, logging-gelf, narayana-jta, reactive-routes, resteasy-reactive, resteasy-reactive-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
2024-04-10 16:19:52,161 WARN  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain] (main) Running the server in development mode. DO NOT use this configuration in production.

I tried to recreate the realms and install different versions of the Keycloak server

Try These steps.
1 Install Docker Desktop for Windows or Mac
https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/

Run Docker Desktop

2 Launch Keycloak by docker-compose
Save as docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.6
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8180:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:

docker compose up -d


3 log in as master admin
Open URL by Browser
http://localhost:8180/

Master Admin Credential
username: admin
password: admin


4 Create Realm , Client and User
Realm name: test-realm

Client ID: test-client

User Credential
username: user1
password: 123456


5 Get Token by Postman
POST http://localhost:8180/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token

In body x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type: password
username: user1
password: 123456
client_id: test-client


6 Get master token by cURL
MASTER_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST http://localhost:8180/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' | jq -r '.access_token')
echo $MASTER_TOKEN


7 Get client token by cURL
curl --location 'http://localhost:8180/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user1' \
--data-urlencode 'password=123456' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=test-client'



Unfortunately it didn’t help... Still the same error from the keycloak server

Did you try "docker compose up -d" with my "docker-compose.yml"?

I added Step 6 get token by cURL, can you try it instead of Postman?

Yes, I repeated everything one by one

Returns jwt with payload:
{
"exp": 1712925858,
"iat": 1712925798,
"jti": "8a5f4dcf-dcc8-4550-924f-b402ef38af95",
"iss": "http://localhost:8180/realms/master",
"sub": "04b7f42c-292c-4111-bbfb-71f4608f02c1",
"typ": "Bearer",
"azp": "admin-cli",
"session_state": "1ba0c46e-a677-4b75-b9a8-e494f2a6e133",
"acr": "1",
"scope": "email profile",
"sid": "1ba0c46e-a677-4b75-b9a8-e494f2a6e133",
"email_verified": false,
"preferred_username": "admin"
}
Does this mean that the problem lies in the postman itself?

I saw you Postman call, the authorization and param's tab is green color. It is not necessary. Can you try Postman call with new POST call with my setting?

Still the same error...

OK, I added step 7, it get client token, can you try it and let me know result.

Steps 6 and 7 work correctly, it seems that the problem is in the postman

OK, my Postman version is v10.24.19. Can you update your Postman and try it ?

Thank you very much for your help. The problem was resolved by resetting all postman settings

Good to hear you got it.
